# Create a custom dataset from a folder with separate files

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

I am using Pytorch's custom dataset feature to create a custom dataset from separate files in one folder. Each file contains 123 rows and 123 columns, and all data points are integers.

My issue is that the resources I've come across cater to files in one .csv, mine are not. More so, opening the images after being transformed as an image doesn't run as well. I'm not sure how to proceed from here on as my code gives:

```
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'
```

```
import os
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from numpy import genfromtxt

# Custom dataset
class CONCEPTDataset(Dataset):
    """ Concept Dataset """

    def __init__(self, file_dir, transforms=None):
        """
        Args:
            file_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transforms (optional): Changes on the data.
        """
        self.file_dir = file_dir
        self.transforms = transforms

        self.concepts = os.listdir(file_dir)
        self.concepts.sort()
        self.concepts = [os.path.join(file_dir, concept) for concept in self.concepts]
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.concepts)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = self.concepts[idx]

        # csv file to a numpy array using genfromtxt
        data = genfromtxt(image, delimiter=',')

        data = self.transforms(data.unsqueeze(0))
        return data
```

Comment: How do you read one of the files? Do you consider one file to be one data point, or does it contain multiple (for instance, one per row)?

Comment: Each file contains 123 rows and 123 columns. All data points are integers.

Comment: What I meant to ask is what is your data structure: how do you plan on serializing a given file into an array?

Comment: Oh, I haven't come across that. I had just assumed each file would be read as an entry.

Comment: It's pretty clear, to me, you need to figure out how to read one file and convert it to a NumPy array before looking into using multiple files. Yet your question doesn't seem to include/question how to read a CSV file.

Comment: I just made an adjustment after reading your comment. I changed the csv > np > image. I'm running into an OSError with the files I'm using saying not found, even though my path is correct.

Comment: `os.listdir` will get you the file names, not the relative paths

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Because it mentions the names but not says not found. So I should be using os.path after that line?

Comment: My initial question was: does one element of your dataset correspond to a single file? Or is it *1* file = *123* rows = *123* dataset items?

Comment: 1 file = 123 rows * 123 columns = 15129 dataset items

Comment: So a single integer is one of your dataset elements? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Each integer in the 123 x 123 dataset (file) is converted to a PIL Image, where the integers are from an API that I'm visualizing into an image. The values do not correspond to any distinct image, rather abstract.

Comment: So yes, a single integer is one of my dataset elements and 15129 of them make up one image in one file.

Comment: Your last two comments are contradictory. From what you've described it's basically: *1* file = *123x123* ints = *1* image = *1* item, hence you have `len(self.concepts)` images in your dataset. And not *"123 rows * 123 columns = 15129 dataset items "*. Did you managed to do it now?

Comment: Thanks for the clear up here. The first one is correct. By 15129, I meant items in one file. The entire dataset is indeed len(self.concepts).

Comment: Not quite. Running the dataset as train_data, the len(train_data) command gives the desired result. But the attribute error with image still exists.

Comment: can you show me the error message you get?

Comment: Checking that Image open doesn't work if the item already is an Image object, I want to switch out the line with another command, as taking it out in totality results in a type error to specify the class.

Comment: With ```data = Image.open(numpy_to_img): AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read' ```

Without: ```TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'> ```

Comment: Realized my implementation has a dimension incompatibility with my model. I added the unsqueeze() function to add a dimension for image_channel as such: [1, 123, 123] but the change is not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`PIL.Image.fromarray`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray) is used to convert an array to a PIL Image while [`Image.open`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) is used to load an image file from the file system. You don't need either of those two since you already have a NumPy array representing your image and are looking to return it. PyTorch will convert it to `torch.Tensor` automatically if you plug your dataset to a [`torch.data.utils.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader).

Comment: When you say, "you already have a NumPy array representing your image and are looking to return it", I assume you're referring to `data = genfromtxt(image, delimiter=',')`

Assuming the transformation above, it still returns `TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'> `

Comment: `self.concepts[idx]` is a string (the relative path to your *csv* file), while `genfromtxt` will return a NumPy array. Therefore your `csv_to_numpy` **is** a NumPy array.

Comment: Yes, I would assume that command should work but the error: `TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>` doesn't seem to recognize its a np array.

Comment: Have you returned `csv_to_numpy`?

Comment: I tested the call (genfromtxt) on one csv file and it works well. Wondering if I'm missing anything here. Also updated the code to reflect what I have now.

Comment: You need to return it!

Comment: Just did. This has worked! Wow, what a session this has been.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Speaking of transformations, however, the array format we implemented seems to raise an error that contradicts our transformation. `TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'tuple'>`

Comment: what is `self.transforms`?

Comment: In my dataset, I assign `self.transforms = transforms` and the transformation I create is as follows: `train_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,)),
])`